# How to backup file from server and keep last n versions?

Tags: windows, backup, batch, robocopy, version-control

I am trying to create a batch script to backup an Access Db from a NAS Server to another server and keep the last "n" versions of that file (n is fixed inside the script), this script is going to to be executed twice each day

The problem right now is that when I copy the file `robocopy` won't update the modified date and because of that `forfiles` cannot detect the last days

The other problem is that I need to keep last n files but `forfiles` only deletes after n days, is there a way to achieve this?

Here is my script so far:

```
@echo off

set numver=20
set datetime=%date:~-2%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%t%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
set filename=scep2012.mdb
set origin=\\supercepsrv\supercep
set destin=C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP

robocopy "%origin%" "%destin%" %filename% /r:0 /w:2
ren "%destin%\%filename%" "%datetime%_%filename%"
forfiles -p "%destin%" /s /m *.* /d %numver% /c "cmd /c del @path"

:end
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about days since you will be running the script a fixed number of times per day. Simply have the files numbered to achieve something like below. Each file's date modified stamp will be an indication of when the backup was made.

- C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb (latest backup)
- C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb.1
- C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb.2
- C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb.3
- C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb.4 (oldest backup)

then in your script have

```
if EXIST "C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb" (
  del "C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb.4"
  ren "C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb.3" scep2012.mdb.4
  ren "C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb.2" scep2012.mdb.3
  ren "C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb.1" scep2012.mdb.2
  ren "C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb"   scep2012.mdb.1
)
```

then your robocopy line.

If there are going to be a lot of them you could do a for loop instead. However you may want to consider switching to using powershell to make use of its more advanced features. Before the batch file becomes too ingrained in your process and switching later would become much more difficult.

Note that before you run this script for the first time, there must already exist a file called  `"C:\Teknia Shares\Respaldos\Sistemas\SuperCEP\scep2012.mdb"`

Answer (score 0):

[timegaps](https://github.com/jgehrcke/timegaps)

> Timegaps is a cross-platform command line program. It sorts a set of items into rejected and accepted ones, based on the age of each item and user-given time categorization rules.

> Timegaps allows for thinning out a collection of items, whereas the time gaps between accepted items become larger with increasing age of items. This is useful for implementing backup retention policies with the goal to keep backups "logarithmically" distributed in time, e.g. one for each of the last 24 hours, one for each of the last 30 days, one for each of the last 8 weeks, and so on.